# How to find process by dmesg message in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, dmesg

There is a "Oracle Solaris 11.4" system, where we have a flood messages in dmesg.

> genunix: [ID 200113 kern.warning] WARNING: symlink creation failed,
> error 2

This messages appears every 15 minutes, but I didn't find any crontab job with this interval starting.

Is there a way to know what is the process runs every 15 minutes?
May I use dtrace or something else?

Thanks

Comment: If your entire message is something like `May 14 21:41:57 hostname genunix: [ID 200113 kern.warning] WARNING: symlink creation failed, error 2`, there is no process.  That's a message from the kernel itself.  I'd suggest looking in `/var/svc/log` for log entries with the same timestamp.  A `dtrace` script on `fbt:genunix:create_symlink` or one of the other `*symlink*` probes should work.  I suspect someone "cleaned up" in `/etc` `/var` or some other system directory and removed a directory the kernel expects to be there.

Comment: One known cause of this is if the system is trying to save a core dump when the directory listed by `coreadm` is not available.